# Getting a similiarty index of a vector of numbers to see how close the numbers are

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two number vectors by how similar their numbers are. For example:

```
vecA <- c(2.1,2.5,2)

vecB <- c(4,4.5,5.1)
```

Would like an index value that tells me how similar the numbers in `vecA` are. i.e. a value of 1 means they are the same.

My attempt at this is a bit messy, is there a better and more representative way to do it:

```
> sum(vecA/max(vecA))/length(vecA)
[1] 0.88
> sum(vecB/max(vecB))/length(vecB)
[1] 0.8888889
```

Any assistance/input is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mean` instead of `sum/length`

```
mean(vecA/max(vecA))
```

---

To make this apply for multiple objects, create a function

```
f1 <- function(v1) {
    mean(v1/max(v1))
}
```